# How to call methods of data member through a generic method

Tags: c#

Considering the classes below, I would like to be able to write:

```
B b = new B();
b.f(1); // calls b._a.f(int)
b.f("howdy!"); // calls b._a.f(string)
```

Class A cannot be modified.

```
public class A
{
    public void f(int i) { }
    public void f(string s) { }
}

public class B
{
    public void f<T>(T v)
    {
        _a.f(v); // fails
    }

    A _a = new A();
}
```

Comment: You will have to use two separate overloads just as in `A`. Otherwise, you are pretending that the user can call `b.f()` with any argument type, which in fact he can't.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The actual class `A` has a lot more methods. So I am trying to avoid this. If not possible, I will probably expose `_a`.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just inherit `Class A` instead of creating a function in class B to handle it?

Comment: If all `B` does is pass calls to `A`, why wouldn't consuming code just use an instance of `A`?  The contrived nature of the example is removing all context of why you need to do this, and there may be other approaches entirely.  (Even if "the correct" approach may involve re-structuring some, or a lot of, existing code.)

Comment: @Tronald It wont make sense, unfortunately.

Comment: @NicoSchertler `void f(dynamic v)` will compile (then you get dynamic overload resolution -- but doooooon't do that). C# generics require type information to be be there. `T` has no type information at all; it could be anything. Unless you give it a fun pass with `dynamic` (but dooon't do that), the compiler has to assume that somebody will call `b.f(new TextBox())`. What then? It'll end in tears.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to simplify your `f` pass-through down to a single method, you'll have to use run-time type checking.  I don't see any other way around it.  Generics aren't going to work here.

```
public void f(object v) 
{
    if (v is int i)
        _a.f(i);
    else if (v is string s)
        _a.f(s);
    else
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

I gather that you are hesitant to just expose `_a` because there are some methods on it that you would rather not be accessible to the caller?  Could you introduce an interface, or would that be considered a modification to class `A`?

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void f(int i);
    void f(string s);
}

public class A : IFoo
{
    ...  
}

public class B
{
    public IFoo A => _a;
}
```

Comment: I cannot add an interface. It is now clear for me that the language does not provide support for what I need.